# How properly to use word discover in English?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Obviously, it is correct to say: Columbus discovered America.
But can we use it as synonym of "learn"?
For example: I want to say to somebody that I learned his code and scripts.
Can I say: "I discovered your scripts"? Or discovered could be used only for something global(e.g. I discovered astronomy) or philosophic (e.g. I discovered myself etc)

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/discover?q=discover

Comment: @Khan yes, I saw it before... but my friend argue with me that "I discovered your scripts" is correct and I want to know about this case. Is it correct to say like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb *[discover](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discover)* means **to find** or **to learn of**, so when you say "I discovered your scripts" you are saying that you found them.

You could substitute *discovered* with *[learnt](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/learnt?s=t)* which is a simple past tense and past participle of *learn*.

> I **learnt** your scripts